# simple json output in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to include in my page, a json object which will act as a javascript object.

I've got it pretty simply in my controller

```
   def index
   @tasks = User.select("task_id,desc")
   end
```

in my view, I thought I'd be able to put

```
 var tasks = <%= @tasks.as_json %>
```

but that outputs

```
[#<Task task_id: 1, shrtDesc: "task 1">, #<Task task_id: 2, shrtDesc: "task 2">]
```

what I was expecting was

```
{"task_id":1, "shrtDesc": "task 1"}, {"task_id":2,"shrtDesc":"task 2"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
 var tasks = <%= @tasks.to_json %>
```

Here are some explanations: http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

Comment: aaarrrggghhh... thanks apneadiving! didn't know about to_json, everything I was seeing said as_json.